# Cannot access library e-resources on campus

Tags: wi-fi, settings, dns

I own a Samsung Galaxy 10.1 tablet(Wi-fi only model) featuring Android 4.1.2. My problem is that I cannot access and use library e-resources on campus although I have my tablets MAC address registered at the computer center in our university and connect via the wireless network available in campus. I consulted the library staff but that did not resolve my issue as I already had VPN and proxy disabled (they told me to disable any proxy and/or VPN). From the same wireless network on campus I can access the e-resources on my laptop and its MAC address is registered in the same database. May this problem caused by lingering VPN and/or proxy settings since I had Tunnelbear installed for some time. I am looking forward to hearing your response and suggestions on this matter.

Edit: I think that it may also have something to do with DNS settings. Can these settings be changed for a particular network without modifying other settings such as IP, Gateway etc.?

Edit 2: The problem is exclusive to Google Chrome, I can browse using Firefox without major problems. Which setting in Chrome might have to do with this?

Thanks

Comment: While I cannot answer the main part (first paragraph), the second one is easy: *Settings→WiFi*, check for the AP, long-press its entry, chose to edit, enable "advanced". Now you can change all that; but it might require you to use a fixed IP address.

Comment: Yeah it requires me to use a fixed IP address and also specify the IP of the gateway which I do not know.

Comment: You can use some diagnostics app (to be found e.g. in the network section of [this app lists](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php) to show the DHCP settings applied currently, including your IP and Gateway. If you enter those values in "fixed mode", it should at least work temporarily (until your IPs lease-time runs out), so you can test settings.

Comment: @Izzy Well thanks for pointing that out, I will try it tomorrow when I am on the campus.